# generate checksum and store the MD5 files is specified folder using maven

Tags: java, maven, checksum

I know that the below command will generate checksum using maven,

```
mvn clean install -DcreateChecksum=true
```

Above Maven command generate the checksum and MD5 files are stored in the `.m2` repository.

I want the MD5 files to be saved in the specified directory. We can provide the below plugin details in pom.xml,

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.ju-n.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>checksum-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>artifacts</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <csvSummary>true</csvSummary>
          <csvSummaryFile>artifacts-checksums.csv</csvSummaryFile>
          <xmlSummary>true</xmlSummary>
          <xmlSummaryFile>artifacts-checksums.xml</xmlSummaryFile>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

But I can't add the plugin in `pom.xml`. It looks like `mvn clean install -DcreateChecksum=true` seems to be easier for me, but it generates MD5 files in `.m2` repository.

Is there any way to pass the location as Maven argument?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing two different things here.

- Configuring `checksum-maven-plugin` to calculate the checksums
- Using the [`createChecksum`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-mojo.html#createChecksum) attribute of the `maven-install-plugin`.

`createChecksum`, being a property of `maven-install-plugin`, will install the checksums inside your local repository and there's no way around that.

If you can't modify your POM, you could still call the `checksum-maven-plugin`. The checksums will be located inside the `target` folder.

```
mvn clean install net.ju-n.maven.plugins:checksum-maven-plugin:1.2:artifacts
```

Comment: hi tunaki, i am getting the below error, `[WARNING] The POM for net.ju-n.maven.plugins:checksum-maven-plugin:jar:1.3-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[ERROR] Plugin net.ju-n.maven.plugins:checksum-maven-plugin:1.3-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact net.ju-n.maven.plugins:checksum-maven-plugin:jar:1.3-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]`

Comment: @Jugi See my edit, it needs to be version 1.2 if snapshot is disabled

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I could see that everytime i generate checksum using artifacts, MD5 seems to be different even if there is no changes in the source file. I know that we can generate checksum using artifacts, dependencies, files and file, which option will be correct to generate checksum of maven project ?

Comment: @Jugi What do you mean by "checksum of maven project"? MD5 is different because every-time you build, you build a different artifact (even if the source if the same, the jar created will probably have a different MD5).

Comment: During every build, i need to get the details of all the jars that have some code changes. For this i tried to generate the MD5 file and check the value to verify whether the jar have some changes or not.

Comment: @Jugi I'm afraid MD5 will not be able to get you that. A JAR is like a ZIP and if you create 2 different ZIP of the same file they will probably have a different MD5.

Comment: is there any other way to accomplish this ?

Comment: currently i am generating the MD5 value for each files using `mvn clean install net.ju-n.maven.plugins:checksum-maven-plugin:1.2:files` and saving all the MD5 values of files in csv file. Then i am calculating the MD5 value of that csv file. This approach is working as i expected but i think still they could be each way for this problem

Comment: Thanks a lot @tunaki. your solution helped me lot to achieve this. Let me wait if any others can provide better solution for this.